# Issues using computed.filter and computed.sort together

Tags: ember.js

Cross-posted at [EmberJS forums](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/issues-using-computed-filter-and-computed-sort-together/6527/1)

In my app I need to filter a list by one or more properties then sort the filtered results by one or more properties. I've accomplished this with

```
sortProperties: ['manufacturer:asc', 'modelName:asc', 'series:asc'],

filteredContent: Ember.computed.filter('model', function (model) {
   return model.get('isActive');
}).property('model.@each.isActive'),

sortedContent: Ember.computed.sort('filteredContent', 'sortProperties').property('filteredContent')
```

The template binds to `sortedContent` via a normal `{{#each item in sortedContent}}`

My issues come when trying to edit an item in that list. Editing the first two items in the list is fine - changing the fields shows the changes in the list with no issues. The problem comes when editing anything lower than the first two items. Any changes get reflected on the proper item as well as other items in the list.

[I've created a jsbin that shows the issue](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/suzad/edit?html,js,output). I'm not sure if I'm just missing something on how I'm filtering/sorting/binding or if this is a bug within Ember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, probably the way you were using the filters/sort that was wrong.

Your fixed and simplified controller :

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['manufacturer', 'modelName', 'series'],
  filteredContent: function() {
    return this.get('arrangedContent').filterBy('isActive');
  }.property('@each.isActive')
});
```

I also mapped the template to loop over `filteredContent` instead of `sortedContent`

And finally two objects had the same ID (not causing the problem but still...)

The working [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nobegaveke/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: that's close but one of my requirements is being able to sort on multiple properties in different directions. I used [a blog post by Balint Erdi](http://balinterdi.com/2014/03/05/sorting-arrays-in-ember-dot-js-by-various-criteria.html) to perform the sorting. Your example does work but does not sort like I need it to.

Comment: It does work on the js bin :

`sortProperties: ['manufacturer:desc', 'modelName', 'series']`

Comment: gah you're right! I tried the multi-sort but must have missed something. Thanks!

Comment: sorry if I am missing the obvious, but where is arrangedContent defined? Where is the sorting taking place?